# busybox man pages paths

Tags: windows, busybox

Is there a standard path where BusyBox searches for man pages? I remember having read something about this, but I can't find where it was. I am asking here and not in the unix/linux forum because I am using the Windows version too.

Comment: Having man pages with Busybox seems like a contradiction. The primary reason for using Busybox is typically to minimize both memory and storage usage. Perhaps you can try to get by with just the (standard or verbose) `help` that can be built-in to each command.

Comment: "*where BusyBox searches for man pages?*" -- Code is the documentation: https://elixir.bootlin.com/busybox/latest/source/miscutils/man.c